# cpanel backup 'cpbackup-exclude.conf' exclude all files except .php and .js

Tags: backup, hosting, cpanel, web-hosting, shared-hosting

my "cpbackup-exclude.conf" has below lines that exclude images:

```
/home/public_html/*/*.jpg
/home/public_html/*/*.jpeg
/home/public_html/*/*.webp
/home/public_html/*/*.png
/home/public_html/*/*.gif
```

i am using shared server.
mostly i make changes in ".php" and ".js" files.
so why entire backup?
thus i want to backup only ".php" files and ".js" files.
as there are hundreds of file types (have different extensions), adding them will make the list very long.
is there any short statement for this?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask questions like this there.

Answer (score 0):

Had to search it myself, but to exclude all ".jpg" files from backup, use this line:

```
*.jpg
```

Do that for every file type / extension, 1 for each line.

Source: [Link to Source](https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/exclude-backing-up-specific-filetype-globally-with-cpbackup-exclude-conf.588399/)

Comment: please read the question properly. i want to exclude all files except *.php and *.js; excluding "*.jpg" is already in my list.